# Removing Desktop Environment from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment

Something weird happened night.  I am running VMWare Workstation Pro on Windows 10 with three linux VMs running on my machine.  For some reason, I found out all the VMs are shutdown this morning.  When I start all of them back up again, I noticed one of the VMs, running Ubuntu Server 20.04, switch from a text-based login to a GUI login.  I don't recall installing a desktop environment on it, and I don't have tasksel install.  I think it's Gnome, but I am not sure. I tried to find my answer on Google, but none of them was helpful.  My questions are how can I tell which GUI I have installed and how can I remove the desktop environment?

If you need more information from me I'll be happy to provide them.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any recent additions to `/var/log/apt/history.log`? You can use those to uninstall.

Comment: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` and `find /usr/share -name '*.session'` might be helpful

Comment: @doneal24 It doesn't look I've installed any desktop environment in history.log

Comment: It happened last night again, so I remote in and open Powershell as administrator to generate a Windows Update Log.  It took a while for Powershell to load, and the screen froze for a moment, then I saw something like logging out "Other User".  This shouldn't be happening as I am the only user for this machine.  Another thing  is the Event Viewer is showing remote connection activity last night and the night before at around 1am when I am sleeping.  Does this mean my system is hacked?  Any suggestions on what I should do will be appreciated.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! It's gdm3.  Removed gnome...

Comment: @skyhon a successfull login attempt that was not you should **definitly** ring your alarm bells. See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @Panki that’s very helpful.  Thanks!